# Return an associative array with certain key for a findBy doctrine repository function

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want this function

```
$entityManager
->getRepository('AppBundle:Example')
->findBy(array('id' => $id, 'active' => true));
```

to return an associative array of Example objects with **ID as keys**. 
For example:

```
array(
    '100' => 'Example object 1',
    '135' => 'Example object 2'
)
```

I can achieve this using `foreach` after retrieving the data, but I'd like to know if there is a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need for doing what you're suggesting, would be to define your own [Custom Hydrator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes). This allows you to define the logic on how to prepare the result after fetching it from the storage engine.

But before going that route, I think you should ask yourself: What's the use case that desperately needs introducing another layer of complexity to my application in order to get the result in a particular way directly from the database? Do you have critical performance requirements? If so, please go ahead with the custom hydrator. Otherwise, just map your results from the objects into the desired structure before returning it, encapsulate that logic into its own class and unit test it.
If you want to skip the hydration into objects step completely, simply fetch the results directly into an array with `$query->getArrayResult()`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set up a custom method in your [Repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-the-query-builder), and there you can pass a second parameter to `createQueryBuilder()`, like this:

```php
public function findActiveObjectsIndexedById(): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o', 'o.id') 
        // ...
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

I just learned this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689187/1668200 and couldn't find any better documentation than https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.html#method_indexBy